# How to make div stick to the bottom of parent div?

Tags: html, css

Could anyone please help me making `div#bottom` stick to the bottom of the parent `div`, so when I click on the button inside it will allow me to show elements from `div#list` above itself?

Preferably I would want to avoid JS, jQuery, etc. or at least in the layout:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div id="top">
     <ul>
      ...
      ...
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="bottom">
      <div id="button">
         <div id="list">
            <ul>
               <li>elem 1</li>
               <li>elem 2</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I answered a similar question before and gave this example: www.jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/5fryQ/11

Comment: your div `.bottom` was missing the `class` attribute just in case you come back and say it was not working :)

Comment: It's a little bit really late, but if you wanted to avoid javascript/jquery, why did you tag it with them?

Comment: it was my preference but not a must to avoid JS

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
.wrapper{position:relative;}
.bottom{position:absolute; bottom:0;}
```

**Edited**

Thanks to @centr0 and @T.J Crowder
the key thing to understand here is that `position:relative` in `.wrapper` will "contain" any element that has `position:absolute`. It's like declaring boundaries for `.bottom`. Without `position:relative` in `.wrapper`, `.bottom` would break out of that `div`

Comment: +1, but you might want to *explain* why it works, maybe cite a reference or two? Mention implications (e.g., other elements will overlap it if they get down that far), etc., etc.

Comment: i dont do this for a living lol :) i simply try n give back something, so when i need help i dont feel guilty :) but im sure `css position relative` on google can explain it far better :) http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp or this page

Comment: but what do you do if your parent is position:absolute already, and you need to stick the div in the bottom of an absolute modal

Answer (score 15):

I run to a similiar problem. The solution from Val is good, but has one issue - the inner div will stick to bottom, but it will not affect the height of parrent div, thanks to its "position: absolute;" (it is out of the page layout flow).

So here is my expanded solution for anyone having similiar problem:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.wrapper .bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

As you can see, I set height of the .bottom ang padding-bottom of the wrapper. Disadvantage is, that the height of the footer is on two places. But I think it is a good solution for example for product list, where there is fixed height in footer of the box (like for price etc).

Remember, that everytime you set "position: absolute;", the element will be absolutely positioned against first parent div, which has set position attribute. Or, eventualy, against the page itself.

Comment: While this works, it overlaps the container on small devices