# Css to make a div stay at the bottom of a div

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am having some html like below ..

```
<div id="dynamicheight"></div>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

if u see the html "dynamicheight" div will get height dynamically on pageload
and i want the "target" div to stay always at the bottom of "dynamicheight" div(as per its height)

note: there are couple other div's in between as shown in html

i am trying to do below css

```
#dynamicheight{
    position: relative;
}
#target{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

but its not working any work around plz...........

Comment: Duplicate [How to make div stick to the bottom of parent div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106181/how-to-make-div-stick-to-the-bottom-of-parent-div)

Answer (score 2):

The selector is incorrect. You are applying to dynamicheight class. Change `.` to `#`

```
#dynamicheight{
    position: relative;
}
#target{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: It works on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zskeH/ Do you mean when you scroll down a page you want target to follow? Then you must use `position: fixed`

Comment: 1 and 2 div's are floating div's

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing CSS for element with certain ID, you need to write *#target*, not *.target*.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

you have used in html `id` or in `css` you have defined `class`

so please change if in `css` `remove` `class` and write `id`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CgtfW/1/)**

**html**

```
<div id="dynamicheight"></div>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

**css**

```
#dynamicheight{
    position: relative;
}
#target{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the markup to be

```
<div id="dynamicheight" class='dynamicheight'></div>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="target" class='target'></div>
```

***or*** change css to be

```
#dynamicheight{
    position: relative;
}
#target{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `#dynamicheight` and `#target` elements are **siblings**.

They'll be rendered one after another in *document normal flow*.

You probably need to manipulate DOM, to achieve this *(**without** removing `#target` element from document flow by using `absolute` positioning)*:

```javascript
jQuery(function($){
    $('#target').insertAfter('#dynamicheight');
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #1](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/zskeH/4/)**.

But, in some cases, it might be better to move the second element into the first one:

```javascript
jQuery(function($){
    $('#target').appendTo('#dynamicheight');
});
```

In this case, you need to use `position` property to keep the second element at the bottom of the first one:

```
#dynamicheight {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px; /* Just as demo */
}

#target {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;  /* Optional */
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/zskeH/6/)**.